# 415 Unsupported Media Type JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am using JAX-ws to generate client code of renderer WSDL. When i try to send the request to the server, i am getting the below. Is there is any thing related to code or any configuration issue or server side changes required??

Code:

```
byte[] tif = //method call to get byte[] data.
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(tif); 
DataHandler inData = new DataHandler(bais, "application/octet-stream");
new MDIVRS().getRenderingServiceSoap().renderDocument(bstrRenderer, inData, bstrFileName, plBeginPage, plEndPage, pbstrImageType, ppParams, ppPagesData, pbstrErrMsg);
```

**SOUP UI RAW input:**

```
POST http://10.96.85.124/MRSMTOMSrv/RenderingService.asmx HTTP/1.1

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1

SOAPAction: "http://mdivrs.myapplication.com/renderDocument"

Content-Length: 10926

Host: 11.22.33.44

Connection: Keep-Alive

User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

**SOUP UI RAW OUTPUT:**

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Cache-Control: private

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: text/html

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 06:09:40 GMT
```

The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

Stack trace
    JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6: Stub for http://11.11.11.11/MRSMTOMSrv/RenderingService.asmx?WSDL

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 415: Unsupported Media Type
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy35.renderDocument(Unknown Source)
at come.on.Previous.renderDocument1(Previous.java:107)
at come.on.Previous.main(Previous.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible reasons:**

```
You have not included Jackson libraries in your classpath
Check your spring XML configuration if you have added below tag or not
Probably JSON data not correctly created. Please check your JSON object before sending request to the controller.
You could use JSONLint to validate your JSON data format.
Check JSON object property name is correctly matching with your Spring MVC controller domain object
Finally check your request mapping in controller.
```

Comment: I am not using spring and JSON in my entire program. So, i will try to keep jackson libraries and let u know. and also i am using eclipse to launch the program.Here, i am passing data as byte[] and here is the code.                                                                                  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(tif);
DataHandler inData = new DataHandler(bais, "application/octet-stream");